# Achieve 'dragged' effect of SKEmitterNode programatically (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have an SKEmitterNode that is used to display a projectile in my game. The emitter follows the trajectory of a bullet, and this is achieved by the following code:

```
let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet") // "bullet" is a blank png
// ...Bullet properties...
self.addChild(bullet)

var actionArray = [SKAction]() 
actionArray.append(SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 1))
actionArray.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())

bullet.run(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))

let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "bulletEmitter.sks")
// ...Emitter node properties... (same position as bullet)    
self.addChild(emitter!)

var emitterActionArray = [SKAction]()         
emitterActionArray.append(SKAction.move(to: endPoint, duration: 1))
emitterActionArray.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())

emitter!.run(SKAction.sequence(emitterActionArray))
```

As stated above, the emitter follows the bullet and animates as it moves. However, its animation is not affected by its velocity. In the `bulletEmitter.sks` file, I can drag my mouse around and the emitter will leave a 'trail' from where it came from. See these two images:

[image: Emitter while stationary - this is how the emitter looks like when it is moving with the bullet]

***Above:*** Emitter while stationary - this is how the emitter looks like when it is moving with the bullet

[image: Trail left by 'dragging' the emitter - I would like the emitter to look like this while moving]

***Above:*** Trail left by physically 'dragging' the emitter in the .sks file - I would like the emitter to look like this while moving

Is there a different way to attach the emitter to the bullet so that it appears as seen in the second image as it moves?

Thanks.

Comment: @ElTomato 'self' refers to the SKScene that the bullet is displayed in.

Comment: I happen to tell that.  So why are you appending the emitter to self?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the bullet is an `SKSpriteNode` which inherits from `SKNode`, you can just add the emitter as a child to the bullet, which will not only get you the trailing effect you're looking for but also save you from having to give the emitter an action sequence to match the bullet. It'll just move along the same track as you've set for the bullet.

(If you do modify the position of the emitter to adjust the desired effect, remember it's now in the coordinate system of its parent the bullet, not the scene itself.)

`bullet.addChild(emitter)`

Comment: Thank you. This makes everything much easier.